# Wamp run as standard user?

Tags: php, passwords, wamp, admin

I already installed WAMP under (windows 7) Administrator account, and it works perfectly ( Green color )! However, I've created another user account as "Standard User". Now when I logged in I'm able to see WAMP folder that contains "wampmanager.exe" but once I try to run it- of course it will require administrator password. How can i force WAMP server to run under Standard User without always requiring me to enter admin password ? is it possible ?

Comment: yes, open yourself a cmd with escalated priviledges and just use the `net start` command to start your server. Then you only need to enter the password once. And if you uninstall apache from wamp (no idea if they are flexible and like it to have to get cut apart), and take the package from Apache.org, well, then you would have a much better control in the tray for starting / stopping / restarting your server requiring as well credentials only once per desktop session. - And yes as well as @MarcB comments, this is off-topic. I'm just commenting a bit.

Comment: I'm going to call offtopic. This isn't a programming question. It's more of a server config/admin thing.